# PHPStorm navigation in source code: How to go one step back?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I am trying to use PHPStorm IDE instead of NetBeans IDE for coding with PHP.

The problem is here:
NetBeans is good at jumping into declaration of any method (Ctrl + Left mouse key). And is good at jumping back (Alt + Left). I know this.

However, PHPStorm could go in (Ctrl + Left mouse key), but not back... Alt + Left does not work for one step back. How to go one step back?

I am working on Windows 8.1 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `Ctrl+Alt+Left` (Navigate | Back)

Comment: By the way, there was problem with Ctrl+Alt+Left on the PC where Intel HD Graphics is active. The solution to the problem could be found here: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-195